# how to access jquery beforeunload-bind form element?

Tags: jquery, forms, onbeforeunload

I'm using jQuery to display a message if a form is NOT posted, using this technique:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function()
{
    form = ... // how to access the submitted $("#form")?
    // here is code to check if form values have changed
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving (submitting the form)?"
}
```

Since $(this) apparently is the window element, how can I find out what form on the page was attempted to be submitted (if a form was submitted)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that rather than binding to `beforeunload` - which will fire even when they **aren't** attempting to submit a form - you instead use a confirm dialog bound to the `submit` event of your forms.

Something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the form?'))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well, I needed to use beforeunload, although my return string didn't make sense. So the beforeunload event isn't related to a form, yet if there is a way to access the submitted form (when the unload is a result of a submitted form) it would be good to know how. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it your way. I would override the submit instead:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
         // display message and return false if they answer 'cancel'
});
```

Comment: Calling `$(this).submit()`, in addition to being totally unnecessary, will trigger the event handler again, resulting in a neverending loop of the user being prompted whether or not they want to actually submit the form and never actually being able to.